Añadir un nuevo objeto al array con setters
package controlador;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Nota[] arrayMsj = new Nota[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la agenda de notas: ¿Qué desea hacer?");
        String mostrarMsj = "1- Mostrar todos los mensajes guardados";
        String anadirMsj = "2- Añadir un mensaje nuevo";
        String eliminarMsj = "3- Eliminar mensaje";
        System.out.println("Introduce el número de la acción a realizar:");
        String opcionElegida = sc.nextLine();
        
        switch (opcionElegida) {
        case "1": 
            listaMensajes();
            break;
        case "2":
            
        }
        
        }
    
    public static Nota[] listaMensajes() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        Nota[] arrayMsj = new Nota[3];
    
        arrayMsj[0] = new Nota(1, "Comprar: Pan, agua, leche, manzanas, carne y embutido");
        arrayMsj[1] = new Nota(2, "Llevar a clase el libro de matemáticas");
        arrayMsj[2] = new Nota(3, "Reunión de jueves: preparar una presentación PowerPoint");
        String lista = Arrays.toString(arrayMsj);
        System.out.println(lista);
        return arrayMsj;
        
    }
    
    public static Nota[] anadirMensaje() {
        for (Nota nota: arrayMsj) {
            arrayMsj[arrayMsj.length + 1] = new Nota(setId(id), Nota.setMensaje())
        }
        return arrayMsj;
    }
    
}

Tengo que hacer una app de notas y me preguntaba si es posible hacer que a un array al que le añades la longitud + 1 (para añadir mensajes) por qué no puede pasársele un nuevo objeto con un setter para que el nuevo mensaje se genere de forma dinámica. No conozco arrayLists ni hashmaps ni herencia todavía.
La aplicación debe mostrar, añadir y borrar mensajes. He llegado a la conclusión de que esto se hace con un array de objetos, pero no consigo hacer que el programa añada contenido al array.

Cuando dices que no conoces ArrayList aún, eso es por que no quieres usarlos? o solamente no los has usado aún?

Eso ni debe compilar. Qué es new Nota(setId(id), Nota.setMensaje())? Dónde está el método setId? En Java no existen "métodos globales". Supongo que deben ser getters y setters de la clase Nota. Bueno, por un lado, solo se usan con una instancia. Por otro, no puedes usar métodos no estáticos antes de que la instancia exista. Debería ser simplemente new Nota(12345, ".....");. Además, por qué haces la asignación en un for each?

No sé a qué te refieres con "setters", yo no veo ninguno en tu código (pienso que puedes estar confundiendo el concepto)
Pero creo que el problema de fondo es bastante claro, quieres agregar y eliminar objetos de un array. Evidentemente por la naturaleza del array esto no es posible y lo "correcto" debería ser usar listas dinámicas.
Pero esto no quiere decir que no puedas lograr el mismo efecto, por ejemplo para agregar un item, lo que haces es crear un nuevo array con +1 de largo, copias todo el array original al nuevo array y al final agregas el nuevo item. Finalmente, sobrescribes el viejo array con el nuevo
Para borrar, sigues un proceso parecido. Creas un nuevo array pero ahora con un largo -1 copias todos los elementos, menos el que deseas borrar (ese te lo saltas) y sobrescribes el original
En rigor, no estas ni agregando ni eliminando objetos, pero el efecto final es el mismo
static Nota[] arrayMsj;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    arrayMsj= CrearNotasIniciales();
    ListarNotas(arrayMsj);  
    
    Nota NuevaNota = new Nota(4, "Otro mensaje");
    arrayMsj = AgregarNota(arrayMsj,NuevaNota);
    ListarNotas(arrayMsj);  
        
        
    arrayMsj = BorrarNota(arrayMsj,3);
    ListarNotas(arrayMsj);  
}
    
public static Nota[] CrearNotasIniciales() {
    Nota[] array = new Nota[3];
  
    array[0] = new Nota(1, "Comprar: Pan, agua, leche, manzanas, carne y embutido");
    array[1] = new Nota(2, "Llevar a clase el libro de matemáticas");
    array[2] = new Nota(3, "Reunión de jueves: preparar una presentación PowerPoint");
    return array;   
}
  
public static void ListarNotas(Nota[] notas) {
    System.out.println("Listado de notas:" );
    for (Nota nota: notas) {
        System.out.println(nota.msg);
    }
    System.out.println("=================" );
}
    
public static Nota[] AgregarNota(Nota[] desde, Nota nota) {
    Nota[] array = new Nota[desde.length + 1];
  
    for (int i =0; i<desde.length;i++ ) {
        array[i] = desde[i];
    }
    array[desde.length] = nota;
    return array;   
}
    
public static Nota[] BorrarNota(Nota[] desde, int index) {
    Nota[] array = new Nota[desde.length-1];
  
    for (int i =0; i<desde.length-1;i++ ) {
       if(i<index) {
            array[i] = desde[i];
       }
       else if(i>=index) {
            array[i] = desde[i+1];
       }
    }
    return array;   
}


Don Yussef, esto es java no C#. Haga usted el favor de usar la notación correcta y poner los nombres de los métodos en camelCase! :) No empecemos a enseñar malos vicios a los novatos

@Benito-B jajaaja! Es intencional, mientras más se parezca a C# mejor será todo

En realidad no es necesario crear un arreglo nuevo si solo quieres borrar un elemento. Podrías hacer de cuenta que el elemento en la posición x no existe. Aunque posiblemente sea más fácil crear un arreglo nuevo. Si el rendimiento importa, lo óptimo podría ser usar una lista enlazada

Vamos a empezar por el principio (guau!), el método main, es la entrada del programa, es el método que es llamado por el sistema, para iniciar la aplicación, poner código en el (además del indispensable), para mi forma de pensar no es una buena idea, primero porque "obliga" a utilizar métodos y atributos estáticos, que no necesariamente necesitamos que lo sean, y por otro lado, parece una forma de evitar la POO, entonces yo creo de debería verse así:
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   new Main().iniciar();
}

Solo lo justo y necesario, su contenido se traslada a iniciar.
Ahora veamos los atributos:
Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
Nota[] arrayMsj = new Nota[ 30 ];
int cantidadDeMensajes;

Como podés ver, pasamos el Scanner como atributo de la clase, para no estar creando cada vez un nuevo objeto, además, arrayMsj se crea con un tamaño grande para evitar modificar el tamaño en cada operación, y para ubicar los distintos mensajes, agregamos el atributo cantidadDeMensajes.
El "ex main":
void iniciar() {
    // creamos los mensajes iniciales
   listaMensajes();
   while( true ) {
      String mensajes[] = (
                "0- Salir/"
              + "1- Añadir un mensaje nuevo/"
              + "2- Eliminar mensaje/"
              + "3- Mostrar todos los mensajes guardados/"
              + "Introduce el número de la acción a realizar: " 
              ).split( "/" );
      for( String msj: mensajes ) {
         System.out.println( msj );
      }
      System.out.println(  );
      String opcionElegida = sc.nextLine();
      switch( opcionElegida ) {
         case "1":
            System.out.println( "Ingresa el nuevo mensaje" );
            anadirMensaje( sc.nextLine() );
            break;
         case "2":
            System.out.println( "Ingresa el numero de mensaje" );
            eliminarMensaje( sc.nextLine() );
            break;
         case "3":
            mostrar();
            break;
         case "0":
            return;
      }
      System.out.println(  );
   }
}

He puesto todo dentro de un while, para poder realizar más de una operación, y añadí las opciones faltantes.
Los cambios no son imprescindibles, solo una forma distinta de hacerlo.
Partimos de una cadena de texto, que contiene todos los mensajes separados por un "/", el metodo split que recibe como argumento el caracter (o cadena) que oficia de separador, se encarga de convertir la misma en un array.
Los paréntesis de la cadena de texto para usar split, normalmente no son necesarios, pero al estar la cadena dividida en varias lineas, si.
El método listaMensajes puede recibir unos cambios:
public Nota[] listaMensajes() {
   String mensajes[] = ( 
             "1-Comprar: Pan, agua, leche, manzanas, carne y embutido/"
           + "2-Llevar a clase el libro de matemáticas/"
           + "3-Reunión de jueves: preparar una presentación PowerPoint" ).split( "/" );
   cantidadDeMensajes = mensajes.length;
   for( int i = 0; i < mensajes.length; i ++ ) {
      String aux[] = mensajes[ i ].split( "-" );
      arrayMsj[ i ] = new Nota( aux[ 0 ], aux[ 1 ] );
   }
   return arrayMsj;
}

La táctica con los mensajes es la misma que usamos antes, partir de una cadena que los contiene a todos, luego separamos con split( "/" ), instanciamos cantidadDeMensajes con la cantidad de mensajes inicial, luego en el for, creamos un array aux con split( "-" ), y creamos los distintos objetos Nota, eliminé las lineas que mostraban los mensajes porque usaremos el método mostrar para ello.
Ahora el método anadirMensaje (y la ñ?).
public void anadirMensaje( String nuevoMensaje ) {
   Nota nota =  new Nota( "" + cantidadDeMensajes + 1 , nuevoMensaje );
   if( cantidadDeMensajes < 30 ) {
      arrayMsj[ cantidadDeMensajes ] = nota;             
   }
   else {
      Nota aux[] = new Nota[ 60 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < arrayMsj.length; i ++ ) {
          aux[ i ] = arrayMsj[ i ];            
      }
      aux[ cantidadDeMensajes ] = nota;
      arrayMsj = aux;
   }
}

He cambiado a void ya que arrayMsj es un atributo de la clase, y debería tener su get.
Primero creamos el objeto Nota, después, mediante el if/else, si no excede la capacidad del array, instanciamos la posición correspondiente del mismo, en el caso contrario, creamos uno nuevo, copiamos el contenido del anterior, asignamos el nuevo objeto y lo devolvemos.
Notece que la sentencia:
arrayMsj[ cantidadDeMensajes++ ] = nota;

aumenta cantidadDeMensajes pero después de haber instanciado la posición correspondiente del array.
void eliminarMensaje( String num ) {
   int pos = Integer.parseInt( num );
   if( pos != cantidadDeMensajes - 1 ) {
      for( int i = pos - 1; i < cantidadDeMensajes; i ++ ) {
         arrayMsj[ i ] = arrayMsj[ i + 1 ];            
      }
   }
   cantidadDeMensajes--;
}

Este método, recibe el numero de mensaje, si es el último, solo disminuye cantidadDeMensajes, (el mensaje no se elimina, solo que no será mostrado, lo que a efectos prácticos, es lo mismo), si no, recorre los mensajes desde el que se desea eliminar, asignando a cada item, el valor del siguiente y disminuyendo cantidadDeMensajes.
void mostrar() {
   for( int i = 0; i < cantidadDeMensajes; i ++ ) {
      System.out.println( arrayMsj[ i ].getId() + " - " + arrayMsj[ i ].getTexto() );
   }
}

PD: te recuerdo que tanto setter como getter, parten una convención de nombres de métodos, podrías cambiar anadirMensaje por setNuevoMensaje, si es lo que necesitas.
